# Thread Behavior:Java Beginner

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to write a program that uses threads, but couldn't understand the o/p. I have 2 thread: `s` and `t`. But I can't see that thread `s` is working.

Can anyone please explain to me the behavior? Thanks

My code:

```
public class Bground implements Runnable
{
    Thread t,s;

    Bground()
    {
        t = new Thread(this,"first thread");
        s = new Thread(this,"second thread");

        s.start();
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("inside run" + t.getName());
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("In child thread" + i);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        Bground b = new Bground();
        try
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("In main thread" + i);
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

O/P:

c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>java Bground

> In main thread0
>     inside runfirst thread
>     inside runfirst thread
>     In child thread0
>     In child thread1
>     In child thread2
>     In main thread1
>     In child thread3
>     In child thread0
>     In child thread1
>     In child thread2
>     In child thread3
>     In child thread4
>     In main thread2
>     In child thread4
>     In main thread3
>     In main thread4

Comment: Just to let you know: Every time you format your code like that, God Kills a kitten.

Comment: Consider letting each thread have a `Thread.sleep(1000)`.  The argument is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect will print out with:

```
System.out.println("inside run " + t.getName());
```

You're not getting the current Thread's name here but rather you're always getting the t-Thread's name. To fix -- get the *current thread* and call `getName()` on it.

Comment: Yeah,Sorry that was dumb..I proved a beginner,dint i ?? :)

Answer (score 2):

You are printing name of the thread "t" twice. that is the problem. on the other hand the threads seemed working to me.
you may want to use this code instead:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Bground implements Runnable {
int name;

Bground(int name) {
    this.name=name;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("inside run" + name);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("In child thread" + i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Bground b = new Bground(1);
    Bground b2 = new Bground(2);

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    es.submit(b);
    es.submit(b2);
    synchronized (es) {
        es.notifyAll();
    }

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("In main thread" + i);
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```